# MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail returns wrong thumbnail instead of NULL

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

Consider the scenario as in this picture:

[image: Native Galery]

Three photos, one of them is a large GIF file (3MP).

I'm querying MediaStore in order to retrieve the correspondent thumbnails. If I initialize the Cursor via CursorLoader with this sortOrder:

```java
MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC""
```

**What happens:** MediaStore returns the previous successfully retrieved thumbnail:

[image: DESC]

**Expected behaviour:** when MediaStore cannot retrieve the thumbnail of a given image for some reason it has to return NULL, as per its Javadoc: *"... Returns A Bitmap instance. It could be null if the original image associated with origId doesn't exist or memory is not enough."*

If I initialize the Cursor with this sortOrder:

```java
MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " ASC""
```

It runs just fine:

[image: ASC]

However I can't simply change the sortOrder since the requirement is to show the newest pictures first.

Below is my sample code and [here is the complete sample project](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=407140000002&name=GetImageFromMediaStoreExampleProject.zip&token=ABZ6GAcGDf13pp4ktibq2Zw1EkoGpJxieg%3A1489362551677&id=40714&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAdwzTpYyb6wV8KipxVBat6rbuvG5g%3A1489362551677) as well as [the three images used to reproduce](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=407140000001&name=imagesToReproduceTheIssue.zip&token=ABZ6GAfiJSB12pLeNiC8Nf7H_HBW2TCCQQ%3A1489362551677&id=40714&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAcCePJNM3_wDBpXptuzQvZHrLqQjw%3A1489362551677).

```java
package com.example.getimagefrommediastore;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetThumbnailsFromMediaStoreSampleActivity extends Activity {

TextView mThumb_id_01;
TextView mThumb_id_02;
TextView mThumb_id_03;
ImageView mImg_01;
ImageView mImg_02;
ImageView mImg_03;
boolean isThumb01 = true; // Simple flag to control this example
boolean isThumb02 = true;
Cursor mCursorLoader;
int mColumnIndex;
long mOrigId; // Original image id associated with thumbnail of interest

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Just initializing views
    mThumb_id_01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_id_01);
    mThumb_id_02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_id_02);
    mThumb_id_03 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_id_03);
    mImg_01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_01);
    mImg_02 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_02);
    mImg_03 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_03);

    // Initializing CursorLoader
    mCursorLoader = initializeCursorLoader();
    mColumnIndex = mCursorLoader.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

    // Go thru all the images in the device (EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    // In this example there are only three images
    for (int i = 0; i < mCursorLoader.getCount(); i++) {
        mCursorLoader.moveToPosition(i);
        mOrigId = mCursorLoader.getInt(mColumnIndex);

        // Update views
        chooseViewToUpdate();
    }
}

private Cursor initializeCursorLoader() {
    String[] COLUMNS = {
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    };

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
    GetThumbnailsFromMediaStoreSampleActivity.this, // Context
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // Uri
    COLUMNS, // Projection
    null, // Selection
    null, // Selection Args

    // Sort Order: DESC = newest first
    // Sort Order: ASC = oldest first

    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

    // *** NOTE ***
    // With:
    //
    // MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " ASC"
    //
    // It runs just fine (MediaStore returns 'null' for invalid thumbnails)
    // The problem seems to reside on the " DESC" tag.
    //
    // How bizarre is that?

    return cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
}

private void chooseViewToUpdate() {
    if (isThumb01) {
        updateUI(mThumb_id_01, mImg_01);
        isThumb01 = false;
    } else if (isThumb02) {
        updateUI(mThumb_id_02, mImg_02);
        isThumb02 = false;
    } else {
        updateUI(mThumb_id_03, mImg_03);
    }
}

private void updateUI(TextView textView, ImageView imgView) {
    textView.setText("ID:" + String.valueOf(mOrigId));

    Bitmap mediaStoreThumbmail = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            this.getContentResolver(),
            mOrigId,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

    if (mediaStoreThumbmail != null) {
        imgView.setImageBitmap(mediaStoreThumbmail);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Does anyone have an idea what may be wrong?

[I filled a bug against Android anyway](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40714).

**EDIT**

It seems that this issue is [fixed in Lollipop.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40714) (The last comment on that thread).

Comment: Print the `mOrigId` for each image you get, it could be the same for image 2 and 3. Or there is a 4th image that overwrites the data. There are several reasons in your code that could cause such an error. Especially since you get just the image Id in your ASC / DESC query, then resolve the image in an unrelated second query.

Comment: Hi! In the second picture (my second link - http://cl.ly/image/2U0z1Z2b1m1v) I put the IDs above the pictures. They are different: 7858, 7854 and 7851.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Especially since you get just the image Id in your ASC / DESC query, then resolve the image in an unrelated second query."

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I've hacked together a small ASC / DESC example which works fine for me (4.0.3 emulator). https://www.dropbox.com/s/in048v3fh3xae2m/AscDescGallery.zip - "Especially..." means: You do in a first step query a list of images from mediastore. Either ASC or DESC. Then you ask MediaStore for thumbnails, in an independant query that does not know / care about how you got the ids. So changing the order in the first query should have no impact on the result of `Thumbnails.getThumbnail` as long as you use the correct ids.

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, thanks for the example. I have no access to the problematic device right now (an ASUS Transformer) but I'll test it on Monday. Then I'll send an update. Just to mention, my example also worked on a 4.0.3 emulator, so it may have to do with the device itself. Thanks.

Comment: And here comes the update: I ran your example in that Asus device. Same issue. Actually with this example both queries (ASC and DESC) get the wrong thumbnail from Media Store. :D

See:

What I have in the gallery: http://cl.ly/image/1W1L023E2B0k

What your ASC example returns: http://cl.ly/image/2P1J220j0T2U

What your DESC example returns: http://cl.ly/image/3Y230t1c1G3a

This reinforces my idea of device-related issue. Weird...

Comment: Weird indeed. The 7851 image seems to be bugged.  Thumbnails, once generated, are stored per default in `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/` - the micro thumbs in a [special file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ics-mr1-release/media/java/android/media/MiniThumbFile.java) (`.thumbdata3-[random number]`), the larger mini thumbs are stored as .jpg files. You could check if what those are okay and maybe delete them + force stop & delete data for "Media Storage" (or translated) app within system settings > apps > all apps. That should reset the complete media db.

Comment: Yep, the thumbs seem ok in the location you pointed out. But I reset the media DB anyway -- no luck. I wonder what kind of sorcery the native gallery uses to read that file, because the native gallery is able to show the thumbnail AND the original version w/o any problems. Well, looks like I'm screwed. :-) I'll monitor the status of the bug I opened against Android. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Same bug happens on my HTC Flyer(Honeycomb), but the result is correct on Nexus7(Kitkat). My walk around is to generate scaled bitmap directly using original image file names(DATA column) returned from MediaStore.images query.  But, it is much slower than getting thumbnails directly from content provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three years, it seems that this issue [is fixed in Lollipop](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40714). (The last comment on that thread).
Therefore I'm answering my own question.

Answer (score 2):

I"m just guessing here. When you ask for the MICRO_KIND the os is creating a new image which gets next in line on DESC cursor producing the same image again.

One work around is to load an ArrayList for the image id's.  Then to go after the thumbnails working from the ArrayList.

Possibility try your code using the MINI_KIND and bmoptions.inSampleSize = 2;

```
 final BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize =2;



                    Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                            context.getContentResolver(), newImageId,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                            bmOptions);
```