# Android duplicate thumbnail issue

Tags: android, android-cursor, mediastore, video-thumbnails

I am creating a custom image and video gallery just like Whatsapp have to allow user to select multiple image/video,so far i am populating and showing thumbnails on gridview.But the result is,on some devices the images sometimes got shown duplicated and on some they do not.same happens with video gallery also.

I am quering the ID of Images from

```
 MediaStore.images
```

and get thumbnails using

```
MediaStore.images.thumbnails.getThumbnail
```

from obtained IDs

below is my code

```
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED;
            imageCursor = activity.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,null, orderBy+" DESC");
            int image_column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int count = imageCursor.getCount();
            thumbnails = new Bitmap[count];
            arrPath = new String[count];
            Log.d("count ", ""+count);
            int i=0;


            for ( i= 0; i <count; i++) 
            {
                imageCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int id = imageCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                int dataColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(), id,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                arrPath[i]= imageCursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            }
```

from [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html) getThumbnail should create thumbnail if it is not available.

one example that produce same issue is [MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail returns wrong thumbnail instead of NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651871/mediastore-images-thumbnails-getthumbnail-returns-wrong-thumbnail-instead-of-nul) but that guy hasn't found the solution (question was asked 2 years ago).

Has anybody faced this problem,i have gone through many examples and to add more i am loading cursor in asynctask so populating thubnails should not be a problem for Adroid OS i guess.Is there a solution available for this issue?Its quite frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've found the solution to your problem yet but I had a similar issue. My app was returning thumbnail uri's that didn't point to anything. But a call to ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() would fix the reference in the content resolver. I ultimately dropped something like the below into my app:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mActivity.getContentResolver(), videoFile.mId,
                                        Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
if (bitmap == null) {
   ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFile.mAbsolutePath, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
}
```

Then I told my adapter to update for the element that was affected.